# It is possible that $ X \simeq \Omega X $ and that $ X \simeq \Omega^ 2X $?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

I am studying J. Strom's *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory*. In chapter 4 he proposes the following exercise

> Let $ X $ be a path-connected non-contractible space.
> (1) It is possible that $ X \simeq \Omega X $ ?
> (2) It is possible that $ X \simeq \Omega^ 2X $ ?

My answers would be

> (1) No, because otherwise $ \pi_n X \simeq \pi_{ n - 1 } \Omega X \simeq \pi_{ n - 1 } X \simeq \cdots \simeq \pi_0 X \simeq *$ and by Whitehead $X \simeq *$
> (2) Yes, for example $X = \prod_{n=0}^\infty K (\mathbb{Z}, 2n+1)$

The problem is that at that chapter no Whitehead theorem nor Eilenberg-MacLane spaces are available,  so there would be a more down-to-earth answer!

What is available up to chapter 4?
Chapter 1: categories and functors.
Chapter 2: limits and colimits.
Chapter 3: convenient categories of spaces, i.e. with CW complexes, their limits and something more; smash product, smash-map adjuction, suspension, loopspace.
Chapter 4: homotopies, contractible spaces, nullhomotopies, abstract homotopies with cylinder and path objects, (homotopy) groups and cogroups, homotopy groups; mapping spaces; maps over and under a space; CW structure on loopspace.

Comment: No, Whitehead implies that $X$ is weakly contractible (there exists a weak homotopy equivalence $X\to *$). In general weakly contractible spaces need not be contractible (e.g. double comb space). Unless $X$ is a CW complex?

Comment: Also what do you mean by $X\simeq\Omega X$? Homotopy equivalence? Homeomorphism?

Comment: @freakish First comment: I was assuming X CW, but probably I have not to do so. Second comment: homotopy equivalence

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing what *is* available by Chapter 4. I happen to have access to this book but in general it's good to make your question answerable without referring to a resource you don't link to, I think.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I edited accordingly to your comment. Feel free to edit more if you find it still incomplete!

Comment: Thanks. I have the same answers as you and I'm not sure what the intended solution is without Whitehead or Eilenberg-MacLane spaces as you say.

Comment: For (2) there is another solution using Bott periodicity, but of course that doesn't seem to have been introduced either; I'm not sure what the intended solution was either